# Python reports different "java -version" from Windows shell

Tags: java, python, windows

When I run "java -version" from the windows command line it says:

```
> java -version
java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)

> C:\Windows\System32\java.exe -version
java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
```

...But in Python:

```
> python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 10 2013, 19:24:18) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.check_output(['java','-version'])
java version "1.6.0_18"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_18-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 16.0-b13, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Comment: So, what's your question?

Comment: You have java.exe in the system32 folder ? That seems to me an unpropper installation anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that python (perhaps because I've installed a 32 bit version) is insisting on using a 32 bit JRE.  I have Java 7 64 bit and Java 6 32 bit - so python opted for the latter.